# How Acess Docker Database Created by Azure-iot-edge By outside Apllication ( Like Python)?

Tags: python, database, azure-iot-edge

I am have set up the Sql module from the edge, which is storing the data from the demo "tempsensor" module to the docker container based sql data base. Data is accessible by the Mssql-tools-sqlcmd where I can fetch the query the database. But when I try to access the database with some other application (I have tried with python), it didn't worked for me

I have tried with pyodbc but its not working! When I tried with ODBC driver installed, I got some timeout error. Then I tried with FreeTDS driver and that also didn't worked for me.

links - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-store-data-sql-server

```
#this shows I am getting the data from the table with sql tool 

  acn-iot2@acniot2-UPC-GWS01:~$ sudo docker exec -it sql bash
```

root@2b08418b1986:/# /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'Strong!Passw0rd'
    1> SELECT * FROM MeasurementsDB.dbo.TemperatureMeasurements
    2> go
    measurementTime                        location                                           temperature
    -------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- ------------------------
               2019-06-10 11:36:46.9392878 machine                                                  21.363193834486001
               2019-06-10 11:36:46.9392878 ambient                                                  20.628800209671599
               2019-06-10 11:36:52.8738186 machine

```
#############################################################################
```

The python code I have used

```
 import pyodbc 
  server = 'localhost,1433' 
  database = 'MeasurementsDB' 
  username = 'su' 
  password = 'Strong!Passw0rd' 
  cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL          
  Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+   
  password)
  cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

I am getting the error like

```
  pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

but when I am trying to read with python I cant read.

Comment: What was the error you got when trying to connect with Python? What code did you use so we can help you

Comment: Hi I have added the details in the post !

Answer (score 2):

Although your code use `username = 'su'` where it should be `username = 'sa'`, but I guess it is not the issue because you are getting a timeout.

I guess you are connecting the database *inside* the container with python code which run *outside* the container.

In this case, you should copy your python code into the container and run, or expose port 1433 and connect to `<container_id>:1433` instead of `localhost,1433`